# sprintf() access violation reading location

Tags: c++, printf, access-violation

I don't really understand this, here's what's going on:

```
char buffer1[100];
sprintf_s(buffer1, "whatever %s", "something");
```

Works just fine.

But the following doesn't:

```
char buffer1[100];
sprintf_s(buffer1, "whatever %s %s", "something", "somethingelse");
```

Error: Unhandled exception Access violation reading location 0x00000005.

I think if I try to split it up with strcpy_s first then use sprintf_s it would work but that would be a waste of everything.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using Visual Studio

EDIT:
Code Update, I wrote the wrong thing really fast. Here's the actual code that's giving the error:

```
sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `username`, `email`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", id, username, email);
```

Comment: Am I reading this wrong, or did you declare `buffer1`, then use `buffer`?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to use fixed-sized buffers. Why are you even using `sprintf` if this is C++ code?

Comment: Richard, it's just an example, I didn't mean to use buffer, I will edit the post.

Comment: tadman, why not? what's the solution to the above error?

Comment: @MarioAda - `tadman, why not?`  Can you *guarantee* that all of your strings will be less than 100 characters?   When I say *guarantee*, I mean that you filtered every single string that will be used by sprintf() to ensure it is less than 100 characters?

Comment: @MarioAda and what is `query`?

Comment: @MarioAda: Based on your update, my guess would be that `username` and/or `email` most likely refer to invalid memory that you cannot read from. For instance, if they are not allocated, or if they are members of a class/struct that you are accessing using an invalid `this` pointer.

Comment: Ah Remy Lebeau, query is sized 1024 same for username and email and that was causing the error, thanks for pointing that out, that was such a stupid mistake, I'm sorry I wasted everyone's time, I should get some rest now Lol.

Comment: Your update is the exact reason why sprintf() is dangerous.  The latest comment by @RemyLebeau is valid, however you have a buffer called `query`, and you're basically hoping that it's big enough to hold that string.

Comment: Yh, I was using StringCbPrintfA before to make sure that the buffer won't be overflowed by a user's input, but I guess this time I was the one ruining everything, anyways...

Comment: Horrible, horrible usage of `sprintf`. Buffer overflow is not your only problem. Now you have to deal with inevitable SQL injections.

Comment: Never Mind. Just fixed the post completely and wrote the actual answer. At first I thought it had something to do with sizes but after, apparently, 30 minutes, I realized what the problem was.

Comment: Hi guys, what is 2 + 2?   *EDIT*: Actually I meant what is 6 * 9.

Comment: BTW my email address is `lol'); DROP DATABASE; --`

Comment: I simply thought it had something to do with size and that's why I made a post out of it but apparently I was wrong, anyways, very funny of you and such an interesting post you got there lol.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was trying to append an integer to the char array using %s.
There's 2 solutions to the problem, it's wither you use %d or to_string to make the integer a string value which will fix the problem.

Solution 1:

```
 sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `username`, `email`) VALUES ('%d', '%s', '%s')", id, username, email);
```

Solution 2:

```
sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `username`, `email`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", to_string(id).c_str(), username, email);
```